# STS eclipse plug-ins disappeared after reboot 3.8.2.RELEASE Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1)

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I have installed subclipse v. 1.10.13 through eclipse market place many times, because after reboot my laptop the plug-in is not longer available, if I check in Help --> Installation details, the plug in is not there. it may be related, but also when I start my lap and open eclipse sts, it asks me to select the workspace, but only shows me the default one,  instead the last one I choose.

[image: Always ask the same workspace]

My lap is a Mac book pro with macOs Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue. To resolve it I did the following steps.

1. Extract the tar/zip file anywhere you want.
2. Drag the STS.app file to "Applications".
3. Now you will see the STS application in launchpad also.
4. Now you can start STS by clicking on this STS icon from
   launchpad/spotlight search.

It should resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this answer, it corrected the problem. it is not necessary to start STS only from the launchpad it also starts fine from the Dock. this answer aplies to the following questions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345829/sts-eclipse-creates-multiple-folders-inside-eclipse-every-time-it-is-opened/40948774#40948774) and this [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260359/eclipse-sts-re-creates-folders-every-time-it-is-opened-may-be-due-to-file-permi).