# STS eclipse creates multiple folders inside .eclipse every time it is opened

Tags: eclipse, chmod, spring-tool-suite, macos-sierra

Hi i asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245743/sts-eclipse-plug-ins-desappeared-after-reboot-3-8-2-release-eclipse-neon-1-4-6) but it did not get any answer, i restated the question.

ok this is the environment.

**Spring Tool Suite
Version: 3.8.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201610040743
Platform: Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1)
macOs Sierra.**

Every time i open STS it creates a folder inside **.eclipse** in this format.

[image: Folders created every time STS it is opened.]

I run this command over the folder **.eclipse** to ensure eclipse has the rights to write and read.

```
chmod 777 .eclipse/
chown -R myuser:staff .eclipse/
```

But STS keeps doing the same thing.

--EDIT

The problem is, every time eclipse STS do this, is like if the IDE were starting for first time, so everything is erased each time the IDE is opened.

--EDIT

Checking the file **locations.setup** locatet in  **/Users/ovazquez/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/setups/** i can see that this file changes every time the IDE it is started, this is the file the first time the IDE reads the config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<setup:LocationCatalog
    xmi:version="2.0"
    xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
    xmlns:setup="http://www.eclipse.org/oomph/setup/1.0">
  <installation>
    <key href="file:/Users/ovazquez/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_1218045591_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/installation.setup#/"/>
    <value href="file:/Users/ovazquez/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/workspace.setup#/"/>
  </installation>
  <workspace>
    <key href="file:/Users/ovazquez/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/workspace.setup#/"/>
    <value href="file:/Users/ovazquez/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_1218045591_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/installation.setup#/"/>
  </workspace>
</setup:LocationCatalog>
```

Then this is the same file once the ide it is opened again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<setup:LocationCatalog
    xmi:version="2.0"
    xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
    xmlns:setup="http://www.eclipse.org/oomph/setup/1.0">
  <installation>
    <key href="file:/Users/ovazquez/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_431833271_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/installation.setup#/"/>
    <value href="file:/Users/ovazquez/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/workspace.setup#/"/>
  </installation>
  <installation>
    <key href="file:/Users/ovazquez/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_1218045591_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/installation.setup#/"/>
    <value href="file:/Users/ovazquez/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/workspace.setup#/"/>
  </installation>
  <workspace>
    <key href="file:/Users/ovazquez/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/workspace.setup#/"/>
    <value href="file:/Users/ovazquez/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_431833271_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/installation.setup#/"/>
    <value href="file:/Users/ovazquez/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_1218045591_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/installation.setup#/"/>
  </workspace>
</setup:LocationCatalog>
```

Comment: Reviewer Comments: What is your question? Do you just want to know WHY it's doing this, how to prevent it, or both? Is it throwing some error that you need help with?

Comment: it seems like Eclipse is doing a similar thing and it seems to be related to configuration data of the installation that you are running.

Comment: Might be better to edit the main question if this is really the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245743/sts-eclipse-plug-ins-desappeared-after-reboot-3-8-2-release-eclipse-neon-1-4-6

Comment: Hi, the behavior it is the same, it the beginning i though it was a problem related to the plug-ins but latter i found that eclipse STS was creating new folders, i tried the previous version and it keeps doing the same, which did not happened in other mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also getting the same issue and resolved it using :

1. Extract the tar/zip file anywhere you want.
2. Drag the STS.app file to "Applications".
3. Now you will see the STS application in launchpad also.
4. Now you can start STS by clicking on this STS icon from
   launchpad/spotlight search.

It should resolve the issue.

Comment: please post your answer here.

Comment: Thank you.It looks like the problem occurs when the STS.app it is executed from inside the default  folder **sts-bundle** which it is unpacked from the downloaded zip.